# Strange float behaviour in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've come across the below behaviour which I can't explain in SQL Server after having been tearing my hair out digging about in some dynamic SQL which was erroring, can anyone help me understand the reason for this?

```
declare @test as decimal(28,2) = 2568595.4
select SUBSTRING(CAST(ABS(@test)*1000 AS VARCHAR(100)),1,2)
```

Returns ‘25’

```
declare @test as float = 2568595.4
select SUBSTRING(CAST(ABS(@test)*1000 AS VARCHAR(100)),1,2)
```

Returns ‘2.’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mystery is solved if you drop the `substring()`:

```
select CAST(ABS(@test)*1000 AS VARCHAR(100))
--> 2.5686e+009
```

`float`s being inexact are often represented in scientific notation.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is meant to store bigger values, `float` has a different string representation than `decimal`.

Consider:

```
declare @test as float = 2568595.4
select CAST(ABS(@test)*1000 AS VARCHAR(100))
```

Yields:

```
2.5686e+009
```

You can see that scientific notation is used.Then when cast to a string, you get `2.`

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d677805e02966f6780b076b2a85104ef)**:

```
declare @test as decimal(28,2) = 2568595.4
select 
    SUBSTRING(CAST(ABS(@test)*1000 AS VARCHAR(100)),1,2),
    CAST(ABS(@test)*1000 AS VARCHAR(100))
```

```
(No column name) | (No column name)
:--------------- | :---------------
25               | 2568595400.00
```

```
declare @test as float = 2568595.4
select 
    SUBSTRING(CAST(ABS(@test)*1000 AS VARCHAR(100)),1,2) ,
    CAST(ABS(@test)*1000 AS VARCHAR(100))
```

```
(No column name) | (No column name)
:--------------- | :---------------
2.               | 2.5686e+009
```